# Scenario where State Design pattern is used

Tags: c#, .net, oop, design-patterns

Can someone point me few real project scenarios where the State design pattern is widely used? Also the main difference between the State Design pattern and Strategy Design pattern?

Comment: this site is great in that it gives a real world example alongside the theoretical one - http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can someone point me few real project scenarios where the State design
>   pattern is widely used?

If you have [state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_State_Machine), and you don't want to deal with switch statements which define behavior of your class depending on it's state, then encapsulating different behaviors in State objects is a good choice. But I can't tell that this pattern is widely used.

> Also the main difference between the State Design pattern and Strategy
>   Design pattern?

These patterns are look like same but there is big difference - with Strategy clients know about possible strategies and usually it's client responsibility to give/change Strategy implementation to class. With State client should not know about current state of object, and about possible states. That's completely internal part of context to switch between states depending on conditions defined in states (state transitions are clearly defined).

Also there is big difference in intent - with State you want context to change it's state dynamically (i.e. switch between states). With Strategy you *can* change algorithm implementation at runtime, but usually you compose context with appropriate strategy (i.e. parametrize object with some behavior) and it stays unchanged. Strategy is more about *sharing* behavior between different classes. States are created for one particular context.

Comment: Can you make it more clear with what you mean by State Machine from a software development perspective?

Comment: @VishnuY by state machine I mean class which has some (finite) number of states, and its behavior depends on current state, which can be changed (state transition)